# C# 4.0 Specification Beta?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, specifications

Can anybody clarify if Microsoft has released a [draft] specification of C# 4.0 yet?  If so, where can I find/download it?

Answer (score 4):

The C# 4.0 Draft Specification is [located here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E).

Answer (score 3):

Try here [C# 4.0 Documentation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1686) it may be too high level for you.

Comment: >>it may be too high level for you
Well... didn't mean to sound all geeky there... ;)

Hm.. yes, as Marc metioned it does seem to miss some key info...
But a starting point nevertheless...

Answer (score 3):

No spec yet, but the [CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en) is available for playing with - but note that this doesn't yet include all the features discussed in the the (preliminary) [documentation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1686) - in particular, many of the `dynamic` features (in particular operator support) are missing (meaning: the C# language / compiler features that work with `dynamic`; for all I know the runtime supports them but the language doesn't yet).

It will also be interesting to see how many of the [new `Expression` methods](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/future-expressions.html) are supported by the language when compiling a lambda.

Comment: Yeah, missed downloading the first day [CTP]... and had to wait for the next 3 days [the links weren't functional] before I could get my hands on the 10GB download...

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, though many of the features have been announced.  The DLR (dynamic language runtime) extensions, which are the biggest new feature of 4.0 are available in pre-release beta form.  My company [www.thinkbottomup.com.au](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au) has used them extensively in case you're in need of any help :)

oh... see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mmaly/archive/2008/03/23/dlr-beta-1.aspx) for further details

Comment: I want to work for your company! My client's still stuck with C# 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the C# Language Specification 4.0 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E)