# Where can I find a comprehensive list of new features for C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0

I've heard bits and pieces here and there, but I have yet find a comprehensive list of new features for C# 4.0? Does anyone know what they are or where I can find them?

---

**Duplicate of:**

[New Cool Features of C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292265/new-cool-features-of-c-4-0)

and/or:

[C# 4.0 Specification Beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408987/c-4-0-specification-beta)

Comment: Duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292265/new-cool-features-of-c-4-0

and/or:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408987/c-4-0-specification-beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get familiar with them is to view Anders' Future of C# presentation

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/

Charlie Calvert also has a blog entry listing a bunch of different resources for C# 4.0 features.  Including a link to Mad's paper which will contain more than enough detail for you.  There are also several comprehensive sample links on the page.

http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/11/04/new-features-in-c-4-0-paper-plus-feedback-and-samples.aspx